# EKS and error creating pods 0/3 nodes are available: 3 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I'm trying to learn AWS EKS.

I have a cluster with 3 nodes (t2.small) and I'm trying to make a deployment to test the autoscaler.

I'm using the latest version of Kubernetes supported by AWS EKS: `1.22` and I modified `deployment.apps/cluster-autoscaler` adding my cluster name and the version, in this case `1.22.3`

After deployment, I see this:

```
kubectl get pod


NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
test-autoscaler-6646b4c76d-grwdt      0/1     Pending   0          5m45s
```

And when I go to EKS and check that pod I see the following events:

```
Warning FailedScheduling    7 minutes   default-scheduler   0/3 nodes are available: 3 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector.

Normal  NotTriggerScaleUp   7 minutes   cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector
```

This is my deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-autoscaler
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: nginx
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: test-autoscaler
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 300m
            memory: 512Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 300m
            memory: 512Mi
      nodeSelector:
        instance-type: spot
```

For deployment I'm using:

```
kubectl apply -f ginx.yaml
```

I'd appreciate help. I was not able to find an answer that works and unblock me.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your nodes have the label `instance-type: spot` assigned?

Comment: better to describe your node and verify that the label is exit `k describe node`